# NotFound component does not render in Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my `App.js` file, I have a few routes enclosed within the `Switch`. The components are rendered depending upon the route. However, there are some components that are always rendered irrespective of the route (`wrapper` and `<Sidebar />` below).

```
// app.js
...
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <Sidebar />
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
    </div>
      <Route component={NotFound} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
...
```

The problem is that the `NotFound` component is not being rendered because of `wrapper` and `<Sidebar />` elements that are global on all routes. I have a couple of questions,

1. How do I correctly show `NotFound` component on invalid routes while keeping `wrapper` and `<Sidebar />` global?
2. Is keeping `wrapper` and `<Sidebar />` global an anti-pattern? If so, how are global components rendered in routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch/children-node)s for `<Switch/>` component says,

> All children of a  should be  or  elements. Only the first child to match the current location will be rendered.

And also looking at the [source code](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/7ccbd7eb7ca603ba164ad75181a48038dd5f4321/packages/react-router/modules/Switch.js#L27) of `<Switch>` makes clear that it iterates thru all children, searching for `path` prop and match it to currect location. So if some children of `<Switch>` are not  or , unexpected behavior will be.

To solve your task I suggest to wrap `Home` and `About` components with HOC, which will render additional required components. For example

```
export function WithSidebar(props) {
    return <div class="wrapper">
        <Sidebar />
        {props.render()}
    </div>
}
```

And use it in `Route` like

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" render={() => (<WithSidebar render={() => <Home />} />)} />
      <Route exact path="/about" render={() => (<WithSidebar render={() => <About />} />)} />
      <Route component={NotFound} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```